# how to show x ticklabel and y ticklabel in three plotted visuals?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, data-analysis

[image]

```
from warnings import simplefilter
    simplefilter('ignore')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex='col', sharey=True, figsize=(12,4))
    axs = axs.flatten()
    

sns.barplot(app_pivot.ab_test_group,app_pivot["Percent with Application"].values,ax=axs[0])

axs[0].set_xticks(range(2))
axs[0].set_xticklabels(['Fitness Test', 'No Fitness Test'])
axs[0].set_yticks([0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20])
axs[0].set_yticklabels(['0%', '5%', '10%', '15%', '20%'])

sns.barplot(member_pivot.ab_test_group,member_pivot["Percent Purchase"].values,ax=axs[1])
axs[1].set_xticks(range(2))
axs[1].set_xticklabels(['Fitness Test', 'No Fitness Test'])
axs[1].set_yticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])
axs[1].set_yticklabels(['0%', '10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%', '60%', '70%', '80%', '90%', '100%'])

sns.barplot(final_member_pivot.ab_test_group,final_member_pivot["Percent Purchase"].values,ax=axs[2])
axs[2].set_xticks(range(2))
axs[2].set_xticklabels(['Fitness Test', 'No Fitness Test'])
axs[2].set_yticks([0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20])
axs[2].set_yticklabels(['0%', '5%', '10%', '15%', '20%'])

fig.suptitle('Fitness Test Comparision Between Group A and Group B')
plt.show()
```

I want to visualize 3 bar plot visuals in one row 3 cols combination, everything  went fine,i don't know why this yticklabels are not showing properly,

Comment: If I understand correctly: you want 3 histograms, the left and right only 4 ticks from 0.0 to 0.2 and the middle should have ticks from 0.0 to 1.0?

Comment: @Gaargod, thanks for your comment.Its a/b testing,i want three bar plots,not histogram,my yticklabels are not properly showing.

Comment: I meant barplots aswell, not histograms, sorry for that.

It seems seaborn uses the same axis for all three barplots. What happens if you change the order in your code? i.e. first load the middle plot, then the first and at last the third

Comment: @Gaargod didn't work though, i changed all ordering sequence